# Outlook addin license token is not passed as ?et query string parameter to the addin iframe

Tags: javascript, outlook, add-in, office-js, officedev

In my outlook add-in, I notice that the license token is not passed as ?et query string at all.
I did some debugging and find out the following:
it seems that the value of the StoreType value within OsfControl is always hardcoded to "exchange" in https://r1.res.office365.com/owa/prem/16.1569.8.2186260/scripts/microsoft.owa.extensibilitynext.js
 which leads to undefined _omnexEntitlment when the etoken is retrieved it's always been retrieved with the initial empty string value.

```js
 getEToken: function() {
            return this._omexEntitlement ? this._omexEntitlement.etoken : this._etoken
        },
```

add-ins (dropbox to outlook import)

Comment: Amr - what do you mean by license token? do you mean the OAuth token from Azure AD ?

Comment: License token is what the store license framework pass to your addin in order for you to validate the addin state then enable/disable functionality based on the addin license state. More about license tokens I here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163257.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The license token is only included in add-ins published via the [Office Store](https://store.office.com). You can replicate this functionality for dev/test scenarios but for production it requires publication in the Store. For more information see [How licenses work for Office and SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn449108.aspx).

For side-loaded add-ins you'll need to handle licensing from within the add-in itself. This is typically done by having the user authenticate themselves when the add-in is activated for the first time.

Comment: Thanks Marc , that's exactly my case the addin is published via the office store and I'm facing this issue which prevents me from limiting the addin functionality in trial mode

Comment: I recommend opening a support incident from your Seller Dashboard. They can take a look at your app records and determine the root cause.

Comment: Over a month now with support with no progress at all Technical support advising me to try general inquiries->pricing app and general inquiries advise me to file it under tech support. It's the definition of a deadlock !

Comment: Have you tried this recently? There was a bug in this area that we fixed in build 15.01.0884.000 - I am wondering if that resolved your issue? And if it does not, what's the build # of OWA for the account you're using (one way to get the version is by calling Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostVersion office.JS API)? Please let us know! Thanks!

Comment: Hi Oleg, I can confirm that the bug is now fixed in OWA. Thanks